# Unroot phone without root access

Tags: root-access, unrooting

I remember rooting my LG G3 like two years ago with Stump Root. Now I don't use root anymore. My bank app doesn't work because my phone is rooted. Now I want to remove root from my phone. I found out that I can remove root access from my phone when I remove the su binaries from the phone. I downloaded ES Explorer to do so. ES Explorer told me that I don't have root access. Now I can't remove the su binaries.

How do I unroot my phone now? And why thinks my bank app that I have root even though ES Explorer and root checker both tell me that I don't have root access?

Answer (score 0):

Install the SuperSU app and go into settings and perform a full unroot... If that fails you will likely need to flash the full factory KDZ image and return to pure stock, be aware this procedure will wipe your device and all user data stored on it.

Comment: SuperSU also tells me the phone doesn't have root access. Isn't it possible to remove the binary through ADB?

Comment: Not without root, kind of a double edged sword, you can't remove the root binary without root, and you can't access root without the root binary... Your best option is to reflash the factory image. https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2785089

Comment: I don't know if I understood you correctly. The su binary is still on my phone. That's propably the reason why the bank app thinks my phone is rooted. So shouldn't it technically be possible to gain root access with ADB?

Comment: @Aaronmacaron Try it... Without the management app it likely won't work but there is no harm in trying